# Jquery unbind click then delay then bind click

Tags: jquery

Hi I wish to unbind a click then delay then bind the click. When the page loads I do not want to be able to click the link for a set period of time.

To be honest I have no idea how to achieve this, I am pretty much guessing how to do it as my Jquery knowledge is very limited.

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $(".colourise-it").unbind('click').delay(4000).bind('click')(function() {
            $('.colourise-it').click(function() {
            $('body').toggleClass('colourise');
           });
        });
 });
```

Comment: Can you specify which version of `jquery` you are using and what is the reason behind unbinding and adding delay and again binding??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to `bind` or `unbind` Just add a `disabled` class on page load as below and enable it after some time:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/49o0yak2/)**

A small **CSS**

```
.disableClick{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.colourise-it').addClass('disableClick');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.colourise-it').removeClass('disableClick');
    },4000);
    $('.colourise-it').bind('click',function(){
        $('body').toggleClass('colourise');
    });
});
```

Comment: @rt840.. Anytime.. :) Please mark it as answer if it helped you!!

Answer (score 0):

> When the page loads I do not want to be able to click the link for a
>   set period of time.

You can use a native JS function `setTimeout` which lets you execute a function after a given timeout.
Wait until a page will be loaded. Then set a timeout for 4000 milliseconds to bind a click and toggle CSS class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".colourise-it").on('click', function() { // ... });
        $('body').toggleClass('colourise');
    }, 4000);
});
```

Take a look at this JSFiddle with a working sample: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xvqvj7b8/2/)

Comment: Im afraid I got an error in firebug "SyntaxError: missing } after function body"

Comment: @rt840. Oh, I am sorry about it. I forgot that I need to click "Update" after code editing :) Check it again now.

Comment: That worked as well but I will use the answer above. Thank you for the help though :)

Comment: @rt840 No problem. Choose the more convenient one. Moreover, Guruprasad Rao's answer is, honestly said, more elegant.